# How to add global shortcut so that it fires command ONLY if unhandled by focused app?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, shortcuts

As in topic. My problem is when I press shortcut in app that has the same shortcut - global shortcut fires instead of application shortcut. My method of assigning shortcut is by using xfce4-keyboard-settings , but I cannot see any checkbox to make shortcut work in "lower priority". I understand some shortcuts are better to resolve before getting handled by applications, but some are not.

I have problem to find solution to my question. I found very few topics related to my problem, closest one was this :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178738/how-is-a-keyboard-shortcut-given-to-the-correct-program

but only thing that I learned from this is how events actually propagate in system. I still don't know how to specifically make event to first try "get handled" in application and only than resolve to "global shortcut".

Should I use different application (than xfce4-keyboard-settings)?
Does propagating event from other side leads to some contradiction that I don't understand/don't see?
Perhaps it's unsure if focused application properly inform OS if it handled event or not, therefore my "low-priority global shortcut" should NOT fire and system should act like application handled it.

Probably I'm missing some knowledge - is it even do-able?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, a global-shortcut and application-shortcut should not conflict (don't assign the same one), you can disable one when you find it.

Comment: Ah, so apparently only option for me is to come up with some different shortcut and change to that. Thanks for answer